# Parse.com: Script error 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, backend

I'm new to Parse.com cloud jobs and I have an error.

I need to make a cloud job that compute statistics out of all registered games in the database ( ~500K ).

My script first draft is :

```
Parse.Cloud.job("dostats", function(request, status) {

Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();


var max_score_query = new Parse.Query("ScoreData");
max_score_query.descending('score');
max_score_query.first(
    {
        success: function(result) {
            var stat_size = 40;
            var count = 0;
            var stats = new Array(stat_size);
            for ( i = 0; i < stat_size; ++i) { stats[i] = 0; }

            var max_score = result.get('score');
            var promise = Parse.Promise.as();

            promise = promise.then( function() {

                var stats_query = new Parse.Query("ScoreData");
                return stats_query.each( function(line) {
                    var score = line.get('score');
                    var id = parseInt((stat_size - 1) * ( score / max_score));
                    stats[id] = stats[id] + 1;
                    count = count + 1;
                }).then( function() { status.success("lol"); },
                         function(error) { status.error("error"); });

            });

            return promise;
        },
        error: function() {
            status.error("Unable to get max score");
        }
      });

    });
});
```

If I `console.log(stats.toString())` in the `each` loop data is correct.

However job fails with this message :

```
E2015-02-10T11:16:54.296Z] v137: Ran job dostats with:
Input: {}
Failed with: undefined
```

Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: Just a guess: Add `});` at the bottom of the file -- statement starting in line 1 is not closed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However it was a copy/paste mistake :/ In my script the final ``});`` is actually here.

Comment: Merging queries would be awesome. However I need to know max_score before looping through every scores to determine the ``id`` where to increment ``stats`` array.

Comment: One last guess: check if `status` is defined and has the expected members.

Comment: In fact if I use ``console.log()`` in the ``then()`` part, nothing is displayed in logs. I can't really know if ``status`` is undefined or not :/ any idea? (thanks for your help)

Comment: So that brings us closer to the core of the problem. Maybe `stats_query.each()` returns `undefined`, so that evaluating `undefined.then()` throws an error.